# Is it possible to Decrypt two different encrypted text to the same identical text value?

Tags: encryption, decryption

I know that in Hash Collision theory, you end up having a collision if two different text strings results into being the same hash values. But my question here is related to encryption.

1) I am encrypting a text "Hello" using Random IV vector as part of my encryption.

2) I am encrypting the same "Hello" text without using Random IV vector as part of my encryption.

The Cipher generated for each of the cases above should be different. But is there any chance that I should be able to decrypt it to "Hello"?

Kindest Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can decrypt both to "Hello".

However, you must always set the IV with a random value that you will use only once. You should also use a high level library, not the encryption primitives directly, or else you are most certainly bound to make mistakes that will break the security properties of the encryption.

Comment: @Ahersean         THanks. "Yes" does it mean I cannot or I can :) ? Sir if you could kindly give a little more explanation I would be grateful.

Comment: @ha9u63ar I've slightly extended my answer.

Comment: @AHersean        brillian sir! I will do more reading on random IV.